# error: invalid conversion from "const ..." to "..." error message when using templates

Tags: c++, templates

So I'm trying to figure out how C++ templates work and I'm not having much luck.  I have created the following templates:

```
template<class TValue>
class Value {
public:
    virtual ~Value();

    inline TValue value() const { return _value; }

    virtual int serialize(unsigned char* buffer, int bufferSize) const = 0;

protected:
    Value(TValue value, const ValueType& valueType) : _value(value), _valueType(&valueType) {}

private:
    TValue _value;
    ValueType* _valueType;
};

template<class TValue>
class NumericValue : public Value<TValue> {
protected:
    NumericValue(TValue value, const ValueType& valueType) : Value<TValue>(value, valueType) {}
};
```

and then I have a class I've created:

```
class U16Value : public NumericValue<u16> {
public:
    U16Value(u16 value) : NumericValue<u16>(value, ValueType::U16) {}
}
```

Unfortunately, this won't compile.  I get an error on this line:

```
Value(TValue value, const ValueType& valueType) : _value(value), _valueType(&valueType) {}
```

That says:

```
error: invalid conversion from const tnp::ValueType* to tnp::ValueType* [-fpermissive]
```

Could some tell me why this is happening?

thanks.

Comment: Conversion from `const T*` to `T*` is not allowed. It would break const correctnes because you could inadvertently change a const object through a pointer to non-const. What's the purpose of `_valueType` member?

Comment: _valueType defines the type of value the object is. The numeric objects provide conversion routines to convert to and from different data types.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your intent, but you don't need a data member to remember a template parameter :o Unless you'd like to keep that info for runtime.

Answer (score 2):

The member _valueType is declared as pointer to non-const object (ValueType*), and the pointer you try to intialize with (&valueType) is a pointer to const object (const ValueType*), since you refer a const reference.

Answer (score 1):

Your construct takes a `const` and trys to store it in a none `const` var. Either remove `const` from that line or add it to the vars declaration.

```
const ValueType* _valueType;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign a const pointer to a non-const pointer.

Change the line to:

```
const ValueType* _valueType;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the ValueType, is it exists at all ? But I think you wanted to do something like this:

```
template<class TValue>
class Value {
public:
    typedef TValue ValueType;
    virtual ~Value();

    inline TValue value() const { return _value; }

    virtual int serialize(unsigned char* buffer, int bufferSize) const = 0;

protected:
    Value(TValue value) : _value(value) {}

private:
    TValue _value;
};

template<class TValue>
class NumericValue : public Value<TValue> {
public:
    typedef typename Value<TValue>::ValueType ValueType;
protected:
    NumericValue(TValue value) : Value<TValue>(value) {}
};

class U16Value : public NumericValue<u16> {
public:
    U16Value(ValueType value) : NumericValue<ValueType>(value) {}
};
```

Comment: That won't work because there is no "value".  These object hold a value and the ValueType object tells it what type of value it is.  The value type is needed for reading/writing to byte streams.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by simply having each of the derived classes return their own ValueType object instead of stuffing it in the parent class.  That seems to have given me what I was looking for.